# Possibility of a Form without a Submit Button

Tags: forms

hope You all have a great day.Here I'm trying to create a form without submit buttons,but when press enter on the text-box the whole text-box gonna hide.why is this is happening?,is it actually possible to create  a form without a submit button or is that is a mandatory thing?,thanks for Your valuable time.

```html
<form > 
   <input type="number" name="cbarcode" id="cbarcode" autofocus/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you hit 'enter' it submits the form.

I believe this is a natural part of a 'form' behavior for accessibility. Input inside of a form is meant to be data the user sends or inserts somewhere which is likely the reasoning behind this.

You can add to the Html form `onsubmit="return false"` or return `preventDefault()` as an event handler / function with other handling code you may want to provide.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;"> 
    <input type="number" name="cbarcode" id="cbarcode" autofocus/>
</form>
```